# Flutter DropdownButton not showing items

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get a list of elements from the cloud firestore and then pass them into DropdownButtonFormField items, the thing is that i'm able to print them in the console but they are not being shown in the DropdownButtonFormField.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> companies = [];

  Future getCompanies() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users_web')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        companies.add(element['nom']);
        print(companies.toList());
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCompanies();
    super.initState();
  }
```

The DropdownButtonFormField:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  hint: Text('Sélectionner votre société'),
  items: companies.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      company = value!;
    });
  },
  validator: (value) {
    if (!isChecked) {
      if (value == null) {
        return 'Ce champ ne doit pas être vide';
      }
    }
  },
  value: company,
  isExpanded: true,
  iconSize: 26,
  icon: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
),
```

I'd be grateful for any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include firestore db structure ?

Comment: Issue solved, as suggested below by @Ivo calling setState was enough here!

Comment: yap, It would be better using FutureBuilder .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your data is fetched async. Your screen is build before the `getCompanies` is finished. The best way would be to use a `FutureBuilder` but calling a `setState` after the data is loaded might be good enough for your case

```
  Future getCompanies() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users_web')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        companies.add(element['nom']);
        print(companies.toList());
      });
    });
    setState((){});
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

companies is a List of Strings so you can put it as is in the items: field

```
BEFORE:
 items: companies.map(buildMenuItem).toList(), 
AFTER:
 items: companies,
```

Comment: Doesn't work cus items take a list of DropdownMenuItems.